# PoolingClientConnectionManager how to close sockets

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

This question is related to PoolingClientConnectionManager (HttpClient 4.2.5 API)

I have max 5 remote connections in the pool and a list of more than 20 url's to download files from. I release the connection after downloading the file. But I don't give any timeout value. What would happen after I have downloaded files from 5 different URL's. I think what I have gathered from the documentation is that the 6th file will not begin downloading till the time the client detects that a connection has been closed from it's end. Is it so? What can I do to close the socket as soon as I have downloaded the file from a URL. Please note that all the URL's from which I am downloading a file from are on different servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Releasing a connection back to the manager does not guarantee its immediate disposal. Most likely the manager will attempt to keep the connection alive. You have two options here (1) as correctly pointed out by [user2310289](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/user2310289) you might want to implement a custom connection that shuts down connections indiscriminately upon their release or (2 (**recommended**)) implement a custom eviction policy to evict persistent connections after a certain period of inactivity as described in the HttpClient [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e652)

Answer (score 3):

According to [The HTTPClient webpage](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/tutorial.html)

The correct way is

```
} finally {
  // Release the connection.
  method.releaseConnection();
}
```

The docs also mention that in order to enforce closure of the connection the most simply way is to override the connectionManager, which in your case is the PoolingClientConnectionManager.

If you look at the code at [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2-beta1/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.java#PoolingClientConnectionManager.releaseConnection%28org.apache.http.conn.ManagedClientConnection,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) your can see that you can change the releaseConnection method.  Specifically change line 255 so that if the connection is open then shut it down.

Comment: So I already do this. But somewhere in the documents it also says that after releasing connections the connection will return to the manager but won't close. In my scenario after I have downloaded 5 files there would be 5 connections with the manager pointing to 5 different servers. But, now when I want to download the 6th file there won't be any free connections in the pool to connect to the 6th server and I will have to wait till a connection is closed by the client (which in my case is connection timeout =0).

Is my thinking correct? and what should I do to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Sorry I am confused as to why you think that "Releasing the Connection" and "Closing the connection" are different.  The reason the "Release" the connection is so that it can be re-used.  BTW, it is the Client which is "Releasing" the connection

Comment: reused to contact the same server or some other server also? I mean after releasing the connection does the socket close or it is kept alive?

Comment: Ah it that case you could call getConnectionManager() and then call closeIdleConnections(long idletime, TimeUnit tunit)

Comment: but for this I'll need to create another thread right? is there no way that I can do this without closing idle connections. I mean I have downloaded the file and released the connection, then too why can't I reuse it with some other server? will I be stuck after downloading 5 files?

Comment: As per the docs you could always provide your own connection manager which does close the connection upon release.

Comment: can you guide me on how to close socket after every releaseConnection call... thanks

Comment: my answer has been modified

Comment: I was looking into - http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html and it says under the description for releaseConnection that I can specify a timeout after which the connection should be termed not reusable... so I am planning to set it to 1 milliseconds.... will this solve my problem and is it the right way? ----- public void releaseConnection(ManagedClientConnection conn,
                     long keepalive,
                     TimeUnit tunit)